# .NET SharePoint Web Service - 401 Unauthorized - Grant Access to Web Service User?

Tags: permissions, web-services

I'm trying to connect to a SharePoint list via a C# console application either using a functional ID or with the default credentials.

Option 1:

```
SpService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Option 2:

```
SpService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw, domain);
```

If I use Option 1, the program runs successfully on my local computer but throws a `401 – Unauthorized` exception when ran on the server.  If I use Option 2, it throws the same exception both locally and on the server on the GetListItems() method.  If I don’t set the Credentials property at all, it also throws an exception in both places.

```
SpService.GetListItems(listName, null, query, viewFields, null, queryOptions, null);
```

I’ve tried to grant permissions to the functional ID in SharePoint, but the Add Permissions dialog cannot find the user.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I connected from a console app, I connected like this:

```
   proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
   proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```